# Execute command supplied by function parameters

Tags: bash, command, function, parameter, bash-script

I'm trying to create a function method in a bash script that executes a command which is supplied to the method by the paramters.

Meaning somethings like this:

```
special_execute()
{
    # Some code

    # Here's the point where the command gets executed
    $@

    # More code
}

special_execute echo "abc"
```

I already tried I `$@`, `"$@"`, `$*`, `"$*"` how could I do that?

Comment: `$@` works for me.. `special() { $@; }` ... `special echo "foo"` gives `foo`

Comment: It did not work for me with: `perl -MTime::HiRes=sleep -le 'for(1..100) { print; sleep 0.05; }'` and `tar -cvf "backups/test.tar" -P "backups/uncompressed_server_backup_(DO NOT TOUCH!)/server/"`

Comment: use quotes around `"$@"`, then you will have more success :)

Comment: Ok. Now it works. it seems like I messed up the code arround the actual call.

Comment: no problem, we all have those moments :)

Comment: Would you say it's simple to detect if there's a flag? Meaning calling it like `special_execute -123 echo "ABC"` Would still execute the command and safe the flag in a value (without the `-`). if this flag is not supplied the variable has a default value. How easy can you implement it`?

Comment: @BrainStone - you'd probably want to use the shift command once you've looked at arg `$1`, which would contain the flag.

Comment: @BrainStone - see my updates to the answer, they include a basic parsing example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think it's just a quoting issue when you're passing the arguments into the function.

Try calling it like so:

```
$ special_execute "echo 'abc'"
'abc'
```

If you don't want the single quotes around `abc` then change the quoting like this:

```
$ special_execute "echo abc"
abc
```

#### Debugging

You can wrap the internals of the function so that it echoes out with more verbosity.

```
$ function special_execute() { set -x; "$@"; set +x; }
```

Then when you run commands through the function, `special_execute` you can see what's going on.

*ps example:*

```
$ special_execute ps -eaf
+ ps -eaf
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Aug21 ?        00:00:01 /sbin/init
root         2     0  0 Aug21 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
...
```

*perl example:*

```
$ special_execute perl -MTime::HiRes=sleep -le 'for(1..10) { print; sleep 0.05; }'
+ perl -MTime::HiRes=sleep -le 'for(1..10) { print; sleep 0.05; }'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
+ set +x
```

#### Parsing argument `$1`

You could do something like this to parse any arguments passed in as `$1`.

```
$ function special_execute() { 
    [ "$1" -eq "-123" ] && echo "flagY" || echo "flagN"; 
    shift; 
    set -x; "$@"; set +x; 
  }
```

#### Example

*with debugging enabled:*

```
$ special_execute -123 perl -MTime::HiRes=sleep -le 'for(1..5) { print; sleep 0.05; }'
flagY
+ perl -MTime::HiRes=sleep -le 'for(1..5) { print; sleep 0.05; }'
1
2
3
4
5
+ set +x
```

*with debugging off - `-123`:*

```
$ special_execute -123 perl -MTime::HiRes=sleep -le 'for(1..5) { print; sleep 0.05; }'
flagY
1
2
3
4
5
```

*with debugging off - `-456`:*

```
$ special_execute -456 perl -MTime::HiRes=sleep -le 'for(1..5) { print; sleep 0.05; }'
flagN
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Why do I get an error saying 'command not found' when using aliases?

Comment: @DrunkenPoney - no such cmd, it's `alias`.